# How do I find a function based on given function values?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let us suppose I have an unknown function $f(x)$.

I have the information that $f(2)=6$ and $f'(2)=-1$.

What would the actual function be? Are there unlimited possibilities? How do I make an expression that satisfies this information?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You cannot tell what the whole function is by the information you are providing. The simplest way to find one(!) function is to chose $a,b$ properly such that $f(x)=ax+b$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple fonctions that satisfy this. The "easiest" way is to consider a polynomial function as
$$
f\left(x\right)=ax+b
$$

You have
$$
f\left(2\right)=2a+b=6
$$
and
$$
f'\left(2\right)=a=-1
$$
Hence an example is
$$
f\left(x\right)=8-x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes: there are unlimited options. One of the simplest would be the affine function

$$f(x)=-x+8$$
which goes through the point $(2,6)$ and whose slope is $-1$ (actually everywhere), as requested.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in other answers, there are countless possibilities. To obtain a relatively large selection of such functions, you can draw inspiration from Taylor's series, where
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n, \quad x \in D.
$$

Any function of the form
$$
f(x) = 6 - (x-2) + \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} c_n (x-2)^n
$$

is a good fit, as long as the series is convergent. In particular, taking $c_n = 0$, you get $f(x)=6-(x-2)$.